# BoxPlots - How to label the bars?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    fmonth        X_state totalDays
    <fctr>         <fctr>     <dbl>
1  January        Alabama 11.407433
2  January    Mississippi 10.469454
3  January       Arkansas 10.436242
4  January      Tennessee 10.374277
5  January       Kentucky 10.124040
6  January      Louisiana  9.417397
7  January     New Mexico  9.199898
8  January  West Virginia  9.167906
9  January        Arizona  8.992925
10 January South Carolina  8.942059
# ... with 43 more rows
```

I'd like to create a box plot that looks something like this:

[image]

I'd like the total days on the Y axis and the states along the X axis. I can achieve this with the following R code:

```
barplot(januaryData$totalDays, main="January", xlab="State", ylab="Total Days" )
```

However, what I'm not getting are the state names at the bottom of each bar, and I'm not sure how to go about getting the state names to appear. By the way, I plan to reduce the number of states shown here to about 10, so the bar plot, eventually, won't look so cluttered.

Comment: you want to pass a vector of the state names to `barplot(...,names.arg = my_states)`

Comment: @NathanDay - But I do not know what the state names will actually be for each bar. They are dynamic and could change each time the analysis is run.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - I don't think this is going to work because the state names are dynamic and will change each time the analysis is executed. Could you show an example of how this could work for me?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - This worked. Thank you. If you create this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple as `barplot(..., names.arg = januaryData$X_state)`